# How can I make a tube with a certain shape?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, transforms

I have the following shape in the 3 dimensions:
[image]

As I'm not sure how to properly express what I want to do, I'll try to do it in 3 (among 6) different ways that I can imagine it. I want to:

1. make a torus that will have the above shape
2. have the shape act as a skeleton for a torus
3. give volume to the shape (turning it into a "tube")

What I have found until now is this answer: [How do you make a torus 'telescope' open?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/how-do-you-make-a-torus-telescope-open)

Using that solution I end up with something like this:
[image]
It covers me almost perfectly except one minor detail. The object isn't a mesh that contains vertices/edges/faces. How can I make that happen? 
Increasing the resolution below "Bevel" in Geometry, adds more detail obviously..but it is still treated as one, whole object and not as separate v/e/f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object mode press Alt+C to convert from curve to mesh

[image]