# Text uv layer texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm trying to do something similar to this is Blender:

[image]

Animation here: https://www.instagram.com/p/BqQKtNmHsCw/

I've got the shape and animation working, but I can't figure out how to animate the text layer on the 4 different sides?

Here's an image of my shape so far:

[image]

I followed this to build the shape: [How to animate text over a twisted mesh (or text flowing along an infinity loop)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135983/how-to-animate-text-over-a-twisted-mesh-or-text-flowing-along-an-infinity-loop)

Also I might need to smooth the object without interfering with the twist or rounding the sides?

**Edit**

This is how it looks when I follow the linked suggestion / open Robin Betts' file:

[image]

I'm not able to determine what Axis, origin the simple deform modifier uses. Is there an addon plugin that I need to install? (I'm using v.2.79)

Comment: Ahh, OK. your 279 is earlier than mine, and indeed, you have no option to set the deformer axes to selected world axes, only to define them using another object's space. I''ll make a version that replaces those settings with objects which define the axes for the deformers and post it up when I can. Hang on in there..:)

Comment: @RobinBetts No need to do that! Just downloaded v.2.8 and now everything works! Now I just need to get used to the new interface. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Cool. I'm still getting used to 2.8 myself, and I have to say, even after a while, I'm finding it slower for modeling. I'm going to have to create a lot of personal shortcuts to replace the standard ones which have been stripped out to clear the keymap. You could always download the latest 279.. it depends where you're at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Material**

A material is set up for the object, coloring an emission shader with an image in the object's UV space, through a Mapping node:

[image]

**Unwrapping**

If you're following a method something like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143785/35559), then you're just unwrapping flat surfaces, before they are modified:

[image]

- There is a seam down every longitudinal edge, so it's just <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap, followed by rotating/scaling in the UV Editor.
- Although the UV space has been set up to allow different text on every face, in this case the UV islands have been snapped over one another, so they all refer to the same region of the image.

**Modifiers**

After Twist and Bend modifiers are assigned as shown in the linked answer ..

[image]

**Animation**

Now the Location: X field of the Mapping node in the material can be keyframed between 0 and 1 to loop the translation of the UV texture space (trim the last  frame, where X = 1 = 0, to get a seamless loop):

Here, the loop is shown without the animated twist: only the text is being animated across its surface.

[image]

Here, with the twist as well..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried quite a lot of different approaches now and most of them seem to rely on the simple deform modifier twisting or bending on an axis - but my version of Blender doesn't seem to have that option? Is it an addon that I need to install?

Comment: @AllanKristiansen  Not familiar with very old versions.. the method [linked from here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143785/35559) doesn't depend on a custom or object orientation for the deform modifiers.. just the selection in them of one of the world axes. The twist is achieved by hooking.. which rotates the mesh _before_ it is deformed. Can you reach the modifier settings illustrated in the other answer?

Comment: It's version 2.79? In the linked approach it's twisting on "axis, origin: z" and bending on "axis, origin: y" in the simple deform modifier module?

When downloading your file, the twist and bend doesn't look like the examples you've shared here?

Comment: @AllanKristiansen dang. Just downloaded my own file to check.. I hadn't included the keys on the empty which animated the twist.,, so have replaced the link. But everything else fine.. just different panels open? What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.79. Yeah it's the same as the last file, but this time just with some keyframes. It isn't bending or twisting in the right direction.

Just added an edit on my original question if that helps.