# How to animate rotation of an object without modifiers

Tags: animation

I'm trying to recreate this rig from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FdoEt9arIk&t=145s)

I've managed to create shape but for animation I cannot find a way to rotate object around it's Z axis without influence on modifiers. Do you have any ideas how to perform this in Blender?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143785/35559) with one more twist? If you parent the both the  Hook Empty and object in the answer to another Empty, you can move it about without it falling apart.

Answer (score 1):

Parent your object to an empty and rotate the empty. So, in details:

- Create your object, put its origin to its geometry, create 2 empties at the exact same point, parent the object to one of the empties, let say the cube.

[image]

- Give your object a first *Simple Deform* modifier, *Twist* mode, *Angle* 360°.

[image]

- Give your object a second *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, *Angle* 360°, with the other empty (here a Plain Axes) as *Axis*. Now when you rotate the first empty (Cube) on the Z axis it should rotate the way you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't help much as I need to animate rotation of object inside of stack of modifiers.

Comment: Maybe give more details about what you want? It's not clear to me...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I just want this figure rotate inside itself like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FdoEt9arIk Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, it should also work with an empty as parent, I've edited my answer  ;)

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much for your help! It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Combined with what previous users have mentioned, you can probably use the Instancer (used to be called Dupliverts) to accomplish this effect. A twist, bend and then have a sphere parented to to the cylinder use emptys to control the axis points for your modifiers. In the Object properties tab under "Instancing" uncheck "Display Instancer" I've put together a blend file that you can check out

---

[image]

1- setup your object and animate it's rotation
[image]

2- setup your modifiers
[image]

3- Twist
[image]

4- Bend 
[image]

5- Instancer
[image]