# How can I create an animated torus in Blender?

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, animation, geometry-nodes

I want to create [this animating torus](https://www.vjloops.com/stock-video/low-poly-torus-alpha-01-169619.html) in Blender. How can I make this?

[image]

This is [a photo](https://www.vjloops.com/stock-video/low-poly-torus-alpha-01-169619.html) of what I am talking about.

Comment: Hello, what animation do you want exactly?

Comment: i need to make the torus with the animation as shown in the link. You have to click the photo on the link to see the animation

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143785/35559

Comment: I see. It's not really a torus. It's six flat circles. Not sure how to get the proper occlusion, but that might get you on the right track.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: So it's not exactly what you want, as you want to keep parallelograms, but I leave my answer:

Stretch a cube (or hexagonal cylinder), subdivide it, hook its vertices to an empty, give it a *Simple Deform* modifier/ *Twist* mode, then a second *Simple Deform* modifier/ *Bend* mode:

[image]

Rotate the empty:

[image]

With an hexagonal cylinder, with a 360° twist:

[image]

[image]

Yours:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you zo much for your answer.  By twisting and bending you will never reach the result shown in the link. in the original work you see only Parallelograms and it is not easy to reach it. i tried to use curves in place of bending, and I used helix in place of the circle used in normal bending. the challenge is how to set the right position of camera. note it is an impossible torus!

Comment: Are you sure it's an impossible shape? See my edit, it looks exactly like an hexagonal cylinder with a 360° twist

Comment: When you compare your result with the original link you see that your result does not contain any parallelograms and that is the difference! By using normal bending the faces will shrink and the original parallelograms will lose their shapes. By using a helix with a curve modifier the original parallelograms will maintain their shapes. only the challenge is how to find the right position of the camera to reach the result shown in the link. By looking at the photo in the link you can realize that is a hexagonal cylinder in a helix curve!

Comment: Oh ok I think I understand what you mean, perhaps you should specify that in your original question

Answer (score 6):

So as you've noticed, this is an impossible shape.  A torus is (mostly) made out of trapezoids, not parallelograms.  And there's no perspective that will turn all of those trapezoids into parallelograms.

But there's not really any such thing as an impossible shape.  Impossible shapes are perfectly possible in 2D.  They're only impossible because they mislead us about the 3D shape they represent.  Your shape is no torus.  It is a collection of six circular rings, viewed from an orthographic perspective:

[image]

One set of those rings is demonstrated on right.  When you create six of them, you have the "wireframe" of the shape you're looking for.  That's easy enough.

After that, the tricky part is getting the occlusion right.  As you can see in the center, manipulating the Z-height to get the right faces occluded is pretty tricky.  I just did this to eye, using vertex weight proximity and local space displace modifiers:

[image]

My implementation of the occlusion isn't quite perfect.  This isn't a shape that was made to be created in a 3D program, it's a 2D shape.  Manipulating the height to create the proper occlusion is a hacky workaround.

There's an armature at the top.  Basically, each ring is moving around a slightly offcenter bone with "inherit rotation" disabled.  The vertex groups to displace the faces in local Z are created from vertex weight proximity modifier, targeting empties that rotate about the center with the rotation of the main bone.

These vertex weight proximity modifiers aren't quite the right solution.  You want every face ripped from each other, and you want every face to displace evenly.  Vertex weight proximity instead creates per-vertex weights that are undesirable.  Better would be to rip all faces, shrink each face to almost 0, and then RGB displace XY in direction of normal to restore the size of each face, so that each face could get proper weights.  But that's more work than I felt like doing.

You'll want the file of course:
[image]

Comment: As I mentioned earlier. it is an impossible torus. To avoid the shrinking of parallelograms by bending using a default circle, I tried to use an array of 16 hexagonal cylinders. After twisting I used the curve modifier with a helix as a curve object. The problem is how to position the camera to reach the best result.

Comment: I think your method is the best one to achieve the result. It is for me difficult to position the bones. I will appreciate it if you can make the same project only for one ring to understand how it works. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @meknassi The problem is that one ring doesn't show anything.  The tricky thing here is the occlusion, because this isn't really built for 3D; it's the "wrong" occlusion that makes the shape impossible.

Answer (score 5):

This is using geometry nodes - I'm still a bit of a noob at it, but the advantage is you can dynamically change the resolution of the torus profile shape and circumference, and even add more twists if you need to.

[image: Animating torus using Geometry Nodes]

The method is simply to create a circle path and have another circle (of 6 sides, say) as the path profile. Then you rotate the path using 'Set Curve Tilt'.

[image: Geometry nodes setup]

I realise this does not address the 'impossible shape' problem, but it looks close enough so I thought I'd share.

Edit: I can get the material looking similar by connecting the Random Per Island through a ColorRamp set to constant, but it only works in Cycles, not Eevee:

[image: Torus with material]

[image]

Here's the file (created using 3.1 alpha, which you may need to grab if you're not already using it):

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned earlier. it is an impossible torus. To avoid the shrinking of parallelograms by bending using a default circle, I tried to use an array of 16 hexagonal cylinders. After twisting I used the curve modifier with a helix as a curve object. The problem is how to position the camera to reach the best result. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7w3noZeo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7w3noZeo/)

Answer (score 2):

Working from moonboots' answer I got a bit closer, skewing the cylinder lengthwise before the modifiers and using an Orthographic camera:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned earlier. it is an impossible torus. To avoid the shrinking of parallelograms by bending using a default circle, I tried to use an array of 16 hexagonal cylinders. After twisting I used the curve modifier with a helix as a curve object. The problem is how to position the camera to reach the best result. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7w3noZeo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7w3noZeo/)

Comment: Camera position (which I prominently included in the screenshot in my answer) is only one of the issues in achieving this illusion in a 3D space.  Camera settings such as orthographic or perspective (and, if perspective, what focal length) would also be crucial.  But if “The problem is how to position the camera to reach the best result” then “How do I position the camera to reach the best result?” should be in your question, not just in the comments.