# how to make the animation looks like it would animate from a whole sphere without gap?

Tags: animation

[image]

So i made this tiny animation, but i would like to improve it in that way, that it looks like that the parts are perfectly fitting to that sphere without gap.

How can i do this?

Comment: Apologies, but what's happening here? Are those things thin wedges that are shrinking into the shape, or are they panels like an aperture, sliding apart?

Comment: just wedges, scaling down and moving inward. like a part of an onion ;)

Comment: Like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/how-do-you-make-a-torus-telescope-open

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Looks very promising...i have to try whether i can transfer that to a sphere ;)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: thank you. Got it. Wasn't perfect, but...with a weld modifier afterwards it works like a charm [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoQsZ.gif

Comment: Neat, complete with a cap! May alternatively be achieved with a screw modifier in a mesh object, if bezier objects are a disadvantage. See answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created/165516#165516

Comment: Yep, also a nice one!