How to animate a sphere gradually transforming into a crescent shape?
Is there a way to animate my sphere transforming from completely round to a crescent shape?

If this were a still image, I would use a boolean modifier to cut out the shape, but since it's an animation, I'm wondering if there is an easier method to achieve this effect?
Edit: my scene


do you mean that you want to do the exact same animation as the one you show?

Same as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/how-do-you-make-a-torus-telescope-open/ ?

@moonboots sorry, i should have been more clear. I have a coloured environment and a sphere that I'd like to vanish. I'm just adding a screenshot of the scene (with unrelated objects hidden to keep it simple) to show the angle - it is not straight on like the gif above

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Oh! So I make a sphere using curve and then play around with bevel factor for the animations? I dont know curves too well but I will give it a try, thank you!

If you want the crescent to be black and transparent so that you can see whatever is behind the sphere like this

you can do the following:
EEVEE: Select one half of the sphere in Edit Mode and press Alt+N > Normals > Flip, so that the Face Orientation overlays shows them red instead of blue.

Then create whatever material... mine is simple black because I started before you edited your question, but it works with a "pearly" material as well, and in the Material Properties enable Backface Culling and that's it.

CYCLES: No face normals need to be flipped, instead give one half of the sphere a material that is just a Transparent BSDF with full white, this will make that half invisible. For the other you need a black (or pearly or whatever) material and you mix it with a Transparent BSDF, as mix factor you use the Backfacing output of a Geometry node.


THANK YOU!! I'll give this a try, it seems like the right solution!

Create a UV sphere, give it 2 materials (black and white) and make it turn 360°?


Thank you! I'm sorry for the lack of information and have edited my original question by adding my scene. This sphere will be a part of a larger scene and the material of the sphere is 'pearl-y'
