Is it possible to animate a curve along it's own path?
For instance if I want to animate a tube going along a path.
So typically, if you want to animate an item going along a curve, you can just create a curve, create you item, then use the curve modifier in order to make the mesh object move along the path of the curve.
But now my question is, is it possible to create a curve, give it some depth in the geometry tab, and have it animate from one end to the other.
Basically the same effect as running a mesh along a curve, but with out bringing in a mesh and using the curve modifier
Is this possible?
Something like this


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65877/how-do-you-make-a-torus-telescope-open/65881#65881

You can animate the Start & End Mapping values with some keyframes:


Right under my nose... lol.
Thanks
